# Training tesseract for reading dates from scanned images

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I have a task to read text from a pdf in python for which I am using pytesseract0.3. I am able to achieve 90%(approximate) accurcy. Though 90% is a good accuracy but the problem is I am dealing with dates and amount, and if even one character is gone wrong, a huge error will be created. I am attaching a sample.[image: here] So the logic is based on when either date or money is there, do something, so if any of date or money is misread, code won't work.

In several cases, these dates are misreading (1/3 as V3 1/4 as V4 1/7 as 1n and so on). After trying with image processing, I am trying to train tesseract for reading these dates better.

I am absolute begginner to training models. I followed some tutorials

1. https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-ocr-with-tesseract-a4341e4564b6
2. https://groups.google.com/g/tesseract-ocr/c/mDMXBmpay9E
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1v8BPw0Dn0I

But nothing worked for me. Different errors in each training method. In the first nnethod getting this error

> class_id >= 0 && class_id < unicharset_size_:Error:Assert failed:in file src/training/common/trainingsampleset.cpp, line 581
> Aborted (core dumped)

And in second and third getting this

> Estimating resolution as 206
> Error during processing.

These errors are too generic, I beleive, as I am not able to find excatly what is the reason for this.
Any help is appriciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are alternatives to using Tesseract Direct from Python, here is a snip of your above image from screen scrapping.

[image]

```
1/3 <Business to Business   299.00  
and board CO    
1/4 ATM Cash Deposit on 01/04 7796  1,500.00    
1/4 ATM Cash Deposit on 01/04 7796  1,100.00    
1/4 ATM Withdrawal authorized on 01/04 7796 Highway 72 W    320.00  
1/4 ATM Withdrawal authorized on 01/04 7796 Highway 72 W    340.00  
1/4 Online Transfer to  111.11  
Zahedian-Fard   Good Pavment History
```

7/8 lines are good so 87.5% line text accurate

90% confidence in an image, is possibly as good as its ever going to be without the source for comparison.

PDF 95% or better should be possible, if its not garbled.

But the source invoice should be 100% (with a fair wind).

> I had a discussion with one commercial provider of data extraction from invoices (based on commercial OCR engines) and their claim that you always need a human validator for fields like numbers, codes, etc, as any OCR is not 100% accurate, but your accounting/service must be 100% correct. So they push for getting and processing data and they try to avoid data extraction from images as much as possible... https://groups.google.com/g/tesseract-ocr/c/IsBlErIb3F0/m/TB8j3WvhAgAJ

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Above you mentioned that there are **alternatives to using Tesseract Direct from Python**, could you please mention those methods, or what have you used to get this accurate result?

Answer (score -1):

The same question is asked in the community [here](https://groups.google.com/g/tesseract-ocr/c/IsBlErIb3F0).

I think this is what you need.